# ruby on rails how to rake db:users:dump?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I want to back up certain table. In other word, I want to clear all database tables, but user db. Is there a command that dump a certain database table, I think, like rake db:users:dump?

I'm using rails 4.2.1 and mysql for database.

Comment: I fixed data.yml file manually and it worked as I thought. In data.yml file, I deleted all but User table.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no `rake` task that is built in `rails` for what you are looking. For dumping entire database schema you could use `rake db:schema:dump`. You can see all the available rake tasks running `rake -T`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dumb full db. Then you can use

```
rake db:dump
```

You can also dump the fixtures and schema. Specific table i am not sure it is possible.

```
rake db:schema:dump
rake db:fixtures:dump
```

Comment: What does fixtures mean?

Comment: fixtures means sample data. They are stored in YAML files and they are unordered data. Fixtures are a testing construct, we use them in our unit and functional tests.